# Harmonic $1-$ form on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, hyperbolic-geometry, modular-forms, modular-group

Let $\Gamma$ be a normal subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

A function $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called an entire modular form for the subgroup $\Gamma$ of dimension $-2$ if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $f(g(z)) = (cz+d)^2 f(z)$, for all $z \in \mathbb{H}, g\in \Gamma$.
2. $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{H}$.
3. $f$ is holomorphic at the cusps of $\Gamma$.

Let $C$ be the set of all cusps of $\Gamma$.

Let $f$ be an entire modular form of dimension $-2$ taking real values at the cusps. It is then mentioned that the real part of $f(z)dz$ is a harmonic $1-$ form on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$.

The questions are:

1. How is $f(z)dz$ defined?
   Is $f(z)dz=f(z)dx+if(z)dy$? Or what?
2. what does **harmonic $1-$ form** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, now write $f=u+iv$ and read off the real part.

A harmonic $1$-form $\omega$ is closed and co-closed. That is, $d\omega=d{\star}\omega=0$. The metric is the usual hyperbolic metric on $\Bbb H$, we assume.

Comment: So the real part of $f(z)dz$ is $udx-vdy$. In this case, the real part of $f(z)dz$ to harmonic $1-$ form it should satisfy $d(udx-vdy)=0$, how can we express that its conjugate is also closed?

Comment: $\star\left(\frac{dx}y\right) = \frac{dy}y$ and $\star\left(\frac{dy}y\right) = -\frac{dx}y$. (The fact that the metric is conformally equivalent to the usual Euclidean metric makes this easy: $\star(dx) = dy$ and $\star(dy)=-dx$.)

Comment: So to be a harmonic $1-$ form, it should satisfy $\frac{d}{y}(u\frac{dx}{y}-v\frac{dy}{y})=0$ and $\frac{d}{y}(u\frac{dy}{y}+v\frac{dx}{y})=0$

Comment: Any good reference for the harmonic $1-$ forms?

Comment: I do not understand what you've written. This is standard, standard stuff. For your context, you might look at the classic book on Riemann surfaces by Springer or the newer excellent book by Forster.

Comment: I have written the conditions in terms of euclidean metric, as you know hyperbolic metric = euclidean metric $÷ y$.

Comment: Am I correct, in my previous comment?

Comment: Can you check out the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084741/the-real-part-of-fzdz-for-a-complex-function-f-defined-on-the-upper-half-p