# The real part of $f(z)dz$ for a holomorphic complex function $f$ defined on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, differential-forms, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $f$ be a holomorphic complex function defined on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$, i.e., $f:\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Then, $f(z)dz$ can be written as follows $$f(z)dz=(u(x,y)+iv(x,y))(dx+idy)$$ Therefore, the real part of $f(z)dz$, denoted by $w$, is $u(x,y)dx-v(x,y)dy$, i.e., $$w=u(x,y)dx-v(x,y)dy$$
Let $A(x,y):=u(x,y)$ and $B(x,y):=-v(x,y)$, then we have:$$w=A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy$$
The conjugate of $w$, denoted by $w^*$, is $-B(x,y)dx+A(x,y)dy$, i.e., $$w^*=-B(x,y)dx+A(x,y)dy$$
It is well-known that $w$ is a harmonic $1-$ form if and only if $w$ and $w^*$ are both closed, i.e., $$dw=dw^*=0$$ that is equivalent to the following two conditions $$\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$$ and $$\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}$$
Am I correct or not?

Comment: No, $dz = dx+i\,dy$. The $1/y$ appears only when working with the metric. But, as I pointed out to you in your earlier post, because the hyperbolic metric is conformally equivalent to the usual Euclidean metric, you still will have $\star dx = dy$ and $\star dy = -dx$, so the factor of $1/y$ is totally irrelevant (unless you want to compute arclengths or areas).

Comment: @TedShifrin I have modified it, I would be very grateful if you were able to take a look at it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(z)$ is analytic then $f(z)dz$ is an analytic 1-form so $\Re(f(z)dz)$ is a harmonic 1-form. For a closed-loop we have $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0\implies \int_\gamma \Re(f(z)dz)=0$ ie. $\Re(f(z)dz)$ is closed. It is also exact because $\Bbb{H}$ is simply connected: $F(s)=\int_{s_0}^s f(z)dz$ is well-defined and $\int_\gamma \Re(f(z)dz) = \Re(F(\gamma(1))-\Re(F(\gamma(0))$. An example of closed non-exact 1-form is $dz$ on $\Bbb{C/Z}$ or $\frac{dz}{z}$ on $\Bbb{C^*}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I mean, in general, if we have a differential form takes on the form $w=A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy$ and we want to show that it is a harmonic $1-$ form, we have to prove that $w$ and its conjugate $w^*=-B(x,y)dx+A(x,y)dy$ are closed, i.e., $dw=dw^*=0$ that is equivalent to the following two conditions $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}$. Am I correct or not?